# Bootstrap Navbar vertically align Brand with other links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically align the Brand in a Bootstrap Navbar with the other links, such that **bottom of each element is aligned vertically.**

The current alignment is either center aligned or just unaligned. The HTML is something like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        <li><a href='#' class="nav navbar-nav">Link1</a>
        <li><a href='#' class="nav navbar-nav">Link2</a>
    </ul>
```

What I see is the bottom of Link1 and Link2 are somewhat higher than the bottom of Brand. Based on another question, I tried something like this.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This didn't help. Even when I increased the line-heigh, everything was displaced down, including the brand.

I just want the bottoms of these elements are aligned, like they are all sitting on a shelf.

Comment: change the question from "Bootstap" to "Bootstrap" hehehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a negative `margin-top` value. In your case `-1.1px` seems perfect.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: -1.1px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Navbar Alignment]